# "de toute pièce" or "de toutes pièces": Are they both acceptable? Is either more common than the other?

Tags: expressions, pluriel

> Il décide de monter **de toute pièce** une fausse histoire de dopage pour l'obliger à quitter le monde de la boxe.

I have always used the plural version "de toutes pièces" myself, but I wonder if "de toute pièce" is just as acceptable?

Comment: I don't think "de toute pièce" is acceptable at all but I have no way to prove it right now.

Answer (score 1):

D'après moi l'expression "de toutes pièces" est bien orthographiée seulement au pluriel pour une question de logique : on parle dans cette locution d'un assemblage de plusieurs pièces.

Beaucoup de texte littéraires emploient cette expression au pluriel :

> Il s'était donc créé de toutes pièces une vie de complications et de drames. - **Camus, Le Colin**

On peut donc compter "de toute pièce" comme une faute d'orthographe, bien que son usage soit très répandu en France.

Je ne dirais pas donc que "de toute pièce" est acceptable.

*If you need help translating what I wrote tell me*

Sources : [Choux de Siam](http://chouxdesiam.hautetfort.com/archive/2006/12/15/de-toute-piece-ou-de-toutes-pieces.html), [Dicoz](http://www.dicoz.fr/de-toute-piece-ou-de-toutes-pieces/)